# SqlDependency in Windows Form application is fast, but it is slow in ASP.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2014, monitor, sqldependency

I have written a windows form application (C#) that uses SqlDependency to detect changes [[From HERE]](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/) . It works well and any changes to User table, fires dep_onchange event immediately.

I used exactly the same code in my ASP.net MVC application and wrote the following code to test it. There are two problems:

1- If I refresh the test.cshtml page, Sometimes the  dep_onchange event fires with delay, or even worse, it does not fire at all.

2- If I add or delete a row from 'Users' table in SQL Server Management Studio, it fires dep_onchange event of windows form application, but it never fires dep_onchange of ASP.net application.

```cs
  public ActionResult Test()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; user ID=sa; password=1234";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "farid");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "Artina");

                        cn.Open();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }


            return View();
        }
```

Global.asax.cs code:

```cs
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            GetNames();
        }


        protected void Application_End()
        {
            //Stop SQL dependency
             SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        }


 private void GetNames()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!DoesUserHavePermission())
                    return;


                SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                    {

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.[Users]";

                        cmd.Notification = null;

                        //  creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
                        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                        //  creates an event handler for the notification of data
                        //      changes in the database.
                        //  NOTE: the following code uses the normal .Net capitalization methods, though
                        //      the forum software seems to change it to lowercase letters
                        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_onchange);

                        cn.Open();

                        List<String> Items = new List<string>();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                Items.Add(dr.GetString(0) + " " + dr.GetString(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception(exception.Message);
            }

        }


        private bool DoesUserHavePermission()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlClientPermission clientPermission = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);

                // will throw an error if user does not have permissions
                clientPermission.Demand();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        void dep_onchange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            GetNames();
            SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;

            dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_onchange);
        }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `connectionString`, use FQDN instead or Windows naming, replace `MSSQLSERVER2014` with (for example) `MSSQLSERVER2014.example.com`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the problem related to connection string?

Comment: Actually, at the moment, my connection string is "Data Source=VIUNA_PC\MSSQLSERVER2014 ...."

Comment: Not really. I may not be able to explain it properly but I had similar experiences when trying to use WINS slowed down my app every time it had to contact the SQL server. After a bit of research I was able to do it with changing to FQDN.
MSSQLSERVER2014 is the instance name then, use the FQDN for VIUNA_PC